# Angularjs - detect when ng-repeat inside ng-repeat finish repeating

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using angularjs 4.2 for my website.

I could detect when ng-repeat finish repeating by using directive but now if I use ng-repeat inside ng-repeat, I can not get scope from repeat outside to check $last.

Any idea about this problem.

Comment: Look at this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit#example it might help you

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer will be use **$parent.$last** to check parent's last iteration

```
<div ng-repeat="item in outerList">
    <div ng-repeat="item in innerList">
        <span ng-if="$last && $parent.$last">
            Last iteration of both list
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the outer `$last` to another variable, such that it's not shadowed in the inner scope.

For example, given `$scope.data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]];` the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in data" ng-init="outerLast = $last">
  <div ng-repeat="j in i">
    {{j}} <span ng-if="outerLast">outer last</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

wil output:

```
1
2
3
4 outer last
5 outer last
6 outer last
```

Working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/N8loT61zuJHdKg8FMygl).